# HttpClient возвращает ошибку 404

Tags: javascript, angular

моя проблема заключается в том что HttpClient всегда возвращает ошибку 404, при этом через Postman запросы проходят.  Я пробовал запускать в разных браузерах, ничего не изменилось.

dataservice.service.ts:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
})
export class DataService {

    constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

    fetchData() {
        return this.http.get('https://www.google.com/');
    }
}
```

angular-app.componenent.ts:

```
import {Component, EventEmitter, Input, Output, ViewEncapsulation} from '@angular/core';
import {environment} from "../../../environments/environment";
import { OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { DataService } from 'src/app/service/dataservice.service';

@Component({
    selector: 'angular-app',

    templateUrl: './angular-app.component.html',
    styleUrls: [
        './angular-app.component.scss',
        '../../../styles.scss',
        '../../../../node_modules/primeng/resources/themes/lara-light-blue/theme.css',
        '../../../../node_modules/primeng/resources/primeng.min.css',
        '../../../../node_modules/primeflex/primeflex.scss',
        '../../../assets/theme/theme.css'
    ],
    encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.ShadowDom
})

export class AngularAppComponent implements OnInit {
    constructor(private dataService: DataService) { }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.dataService.fetchData().subscribe(data => {
            console.log(data);
        });}
}
```

Ошибка :
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Подскажите, с чем это может быть связано?

Comment: Попробуй [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42389962/2881286) посмотреть, возможно где-то используется `in-memory api